# 8 - Register form automatically fills in input fields

Tags: theming, 8, users

I am using the core `user-register-form` to let users register to my site. When I first want to register a new account the form is displayed as followed:

[image]

Now, when I enter credentials and submit the form, the user is created. I can login and out with the created user.

However, if I want to register ANOTHER new account the form automatically fills in the e-mail and username of the user I just created.

[image]

I have tried several things that did not solve the problem:

- Clear Drupal cache
- Close browser and re-open
- Kill browser and re-open
- Open incognito browser
- Clear browser cache
- Disabled browser auto-fill

I also tried clearing the inputs using jQuery `val('');` but then the form doesn't submit properly.

I assume this has something to do with drupal core? Please advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to the [Drupal Community](https://www.drupal.org/node/2409107)

Apparently this is defined in the core of Drupal: `core/modules/user/src/RegisterForm.php`

The following should be set to `FALSE`

```
// For non-admin users, populate the form fields using data from the browser.
    if (!$admin) {
      $form['#attributes']['data-user-info-from-browser'] = TRUE;
    }
```

However it would be better to not mess with the core values and write a `form_hook_alter` instead in your theme file:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) {
  if ( TRUE === in_array( $form_id, array( 'user_register_form') ) ) {
    $form['#attributes']['data-user-info-from-browser'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

This solved the problem.